# Is it possible to integrate c++ unit tests into a maven build process and if yes with which unit testing framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, maven

We are planning to integrate our native c++ projects into a maven build process. Further we want to formulate unit tests that are run automatically using the standard maven syntax (as for java unit tests) also for the c++ projects. Is this possible with c++ unit testing frameworks and if yes, which framework integrates well with maven ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a deep look into the [maven-nar-plugin](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/) in relationship with Boost library which should fit your needs.

Comment: So have you used boost::test together with nar ? I have used boost::test and come to like it but i found nothing maven nar related in the context of booost test